# Crashreport from Xcode, no idea how to read

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I know its a bit awkward asking this, but I have no idea how to read this crash report and find the position and cause of this error described in the following crash-report.

Can someone help me ?

Any hint, where to look, or howto navigate to the code in Xcode ? There is no way to jump to the code

```
Incident Identifier: A4091FA2-B415-4BB2-8BC5-E8A0251CABB2
    CrashReporter Key:   498b5fdb26267e3c2dc7c8bfa44ea1cf8df48663
    Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
    Process:             MyApp [618]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Identifier:          com.mycompany.MyApp
    Version:             4 (1.02)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2016-04-18 16:55:02.02 +0200
    Launch Time:         2016-04-17 22:50:46.46 +0200
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
    Triggered by Thread:  7

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x24d0b986 __exceptionPreprocess + 122 (NSException.m:162)
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x244a6e12 objc_exception_throw + 34 (objc-exception.mm:531)
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x24d11320 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184 (NSObject.m:333)
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x24d0ef4c ___forwarding___ + 696 (NSForwarding.m:3149)
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c3a2f4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20 (NSForwarding.s:641)
    5   UIFoundation                    0x291fe402 +[NSStringDrawingTextStorageSettings threadSpecificStringDrawingTextStorageSettings:] + 58 (NSStringDrawingTextStorage.m:357)
    6   UIFoundation                    0x291f35b2 +[NSString(NSStringDrawing) typesetterBehavior] + 30 (NSStringDrawing.m:724)
    7   UIFoundation                    0x291f4ab6 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 294 (NSStringDrawing.m:2413)
    8   UIFoundation                    0x291f4978 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 128 (NSStringDrawing.m:1734)
    9   UIKit                           0x29282bd6 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 790 (UILabel.m:930)
    10  UIKit                           0x2933c978 -[UIButton _titleRectForContentRect:calculatePositionForEmptyTitle:] + 916 (UIButton.m:2744)
    11  UIKit                           0x2933c5cc -[UIButton titleRectForContentRect:] + 48 (UIButton.m:2817)
    12  UIKit                           0x297209fe -[UIButton _layoutTitleView] + 142 (UIButton.m:3542)
    13  UIKit                           0x292cfaf8 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 280 (UIButton.m:3577)
    14  UIKit                           0x2927399e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710 (UIView.m:11881)
    15  QuartzCore                      0x27319b48 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 124 (CALayer.mm:8899)
    16  QuartzCore                      0x27315220 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 344 (CALayer.mm:8779)
    17  QuartzCore                      0x273150b4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12 (CALayer.mm:2524)
    18  QuartzCore                      0x2731457c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 364 (CAContextInternal.mm:1627)
    19  QuartzCore                      0x2731422e CA::Transaction::commit() + 610 (CATransactionInternal.mm:417)
    20  QuartzCore                      0x27341ea6 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 306 (CATransactionInternal.mm:545)
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3e548 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 504 (pthread_tsd.c:216)
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3e14a _pthread_exit + 82 (pthread.c:1308)
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3db38 _pthread_wqthread + 1040 (pthread.c:1930)
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d714 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:146)

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    8.730414     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x1f18c00] Decoding completed without errors
    8.731832     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x1f18c00] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    8.731832     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x1f18c00] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 13408
    8.843142     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1f18c00] Created session
    8.843142     AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1f18c00] Releasing session
    8.923709     AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1f18c00] Created session
    17.965940    AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x1528800] Decoding completed without errors
    17.967235    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x1528800] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    17.967235    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x1528800] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 7306
    18.102591    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1528800] Created session
    18.102591    AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1528800] Releasing session
    18.118059    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1528800] Created session
    38.172350    AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x1330600] Decoding completed without errors
    38.173946    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x1330600] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    38.174204    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x1330600] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 9637
    38.435199    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1330600] Created session
    38.435985    AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7dc00] Releasing session
    44.306433    AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x1601400] Decoding completed without errors
    44.311119    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x1601400] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    44.311119    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x1601400] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 10506
    44.318073    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1601400] Created session
    44.319068    AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7b200] Releasing session
    44.359825    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1c7dc00] Created session
    44.362915    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1c7b200] Created session
    45.738498    AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7dc00] Releasing session
    142.434210   AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x1c7dc00] Decoding completed without errors
    142.437066   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x1c7dc00] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    142.437067   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x1c7dc00] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 9637
    142.440580   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1c7dc00] Created session
    142.440736   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7dc00] Releasing session
    143.774184   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x1c7dc00] Created session
    145.513306   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x169e600] Releasing session
    145.513306   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1601400] Releasing session
    145.513307   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7b200] Releasing session
    145.513307   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1c7dc00] Releasing session
    185.122245   AppleJPEG                  0x000000002644b397 [0x169e600] Decoding completed without errors
    185.123985   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449a47 [0x169e600] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    185.123985   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026449927 [0x169e600] Decoding: C0 0x00C800C8 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 9096
    185.130467   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x169e600] Created session
    185.130467   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x169e600] Releasing session
    185.166328   AppleJPEG                  0x0000000026448dd1 [0x169e600] Created session
    222.626114   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1e25000] Releasing session
    222.626114   AppleJPEG                  0x00000000264494f9 [0x1e80a00] Releasing session

    Thread 0 name:
    Thread 0:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249828d0 mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249826d4 mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:103)
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccdb34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccbebc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036 (CFRunLoop.c:2607)
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b2e8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b0d4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
    6   GraphicsServices                0x2620bac8 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2245)
    7   UIKit                           0x292e00b8 UIApplicationMain + 144 (UIApplication.m:3772)
    8   MyApp               0x00101d6c main + 180 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
    9   libdyld.dylib                   0x248c3872 start + 2 (start_glue.s:64)

    Thread 1 name:
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249982f8 kevent_qos + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x2488dd60 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 256 (source.c:2542)
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x2488dabe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 38 (source.c:2573)

    Thread 2 name:
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249828d0 mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249826d4 mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:103)
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccdb34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccbebc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036 (CFRunLoop.c:2607)
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b2e8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b0d4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
    6   CFNetwork                       0x2526c946 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486 (NSURLConnection.mm:325)
    7   Foundation                      0x25535484 __NSThread__start__ + 1148 (NSThread.m:1134)
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f85a _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f7ce _pthread_start + 110 (pthread.c:692)
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d724 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:162)

    Thread 3 name:
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x24996eec __select + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x24cd2f82 __CFSocketManager + 566 (CFSocket.c:2128)
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f85a _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f7ce _pthread_start + 110 (pthread.c:692)
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d724 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:162)

    Thread 4 name:
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249828d0 mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249826d4 mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:103)
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccdb34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccbebc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036 (CFRunLoop.c:2607)
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b2e8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b0d4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
    6   WebCore                         0x283e307e RunWebThread(void*) + 422 (WebCoreThread.mm:692)
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f85a _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f7ce _pthread_start + 110 (pthread.c:692)
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d724 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:162)

    Thread 5 name:
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x24996998 __psynch_cvwait + 24
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3edec _pthread_cond_wait + 536 (pthread_cond.c:536)
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3fc98 pthread_cond_wait + 40 (pthread_cancelable.c:310)
    3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x2443c86c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 36 (condition_variable.cpp:40)
    4   JavaScriptCore                  0x27fbe8c4 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 104 (__mutex_base:344)
    5   JavaScriptCore                  0x27fbe92e JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 58 (GCThread.cpp:97)
    6   JavaScriptCore                  0x27dcfa60 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 148 (functional:1793)
    7   JavaScriptCore                  0x27dcf9be WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14 (ThreadingPthreads.cpp:170)
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f85a _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f7ce _pthread_start + 110 (pthread.c:692)
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d724 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:162)

    Thread 6 name:
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249828d0 mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x249826d4 mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:103)
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccdb34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x24ccbebc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036 (CFRunLoop.c:2607)
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b2e8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x24c1b0d4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
    6   WebCore                         0x28406fbc WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 268 (LoaderRunLoopCF.cpp:79)
    7   JavaScriptCore                  0x27dcfa60 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 148 (functional:1793)
    8   JavaScriptCore                  0x27dcf9be WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14 (ThreadingPthreads.cpp:170)
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f85a _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3f7ce _pthread_start + 110 (pthread.c:692)
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d724 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:162)

    Thread 7 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x2492b13e __abort + 134 (abort.c:140)
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x2492b0b8 abort + 120 (abort.c:99)
    2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x24482ae4 abort_message + 108 (abort_message.cpp:47)
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2449b69e default_terminate_handler() + 266 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x244a70b0 _objc_terminate() + 192 (objc-exception.mm:678)
    5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x24498e16 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78 (cxa_handlers.cpp:67)
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x244985f4 __cxa_throw + 112 (cxa_exception.cpp:147)
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x244a6eea objc_exception_throw + 250 (objc-exception.mm:567)
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x24d11324 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 188 (NSObject.m:333)
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x24d0ef50 ___forwarding___ + 700 (NSForwarding.m:3149)
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x24c3a2f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24 (NSForwarding.s:642)
    11  UIFoundation                    0x291fe406 +[NSStringDrawingTextStorageSettings threadSpecificStringDrawingTextStorageSettings:] + 62 (NSStringDrawingTextStorage.m:357)
    12  UIFoundation                    0x291f35b6 +[NSString(NSStringDrawing) typesetterBehavior] + 34 (NSStringDrawing.m:724)
    13  UIFoundation                    0x291f4aba __NSStringDrawingEngine + 298 (NSStringDrawing.m:2413)
    14  UIFoundation                    0x291f497c -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 132 (NSStringDrawing.m:1734)
    15  UIKit                           0x29282bda -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 794 (UILabel.m:930)
    16  UIKit                           0x2933c97c -[UIButton _titleRectForContentRect:calculatePositionForEmptyTitle:] + 920 (UIButton.m:2744)
    17  UIKit                           0x2933c5d0 -[UIButton titleRectForContentRect:] + 52 (UIButton.m:2817)
    18  UIKit                           0x29720a02 -[UIButton _layoutTitleView] + 146 (UIButton.m:3542)
    19  UIKit                           0x292cfafc -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 284 (UIButton.m:3577)
    20  UIKit                           0x292739a2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 714 (UIView.m:11881)
    21  QuartzCore                      0x27319b4c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128 (CALayer.mm:8899)
    22  QuartzCore                      0x27315224 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 348 (CALayer.mm:8779)
    23  QuartzCore                      0x273150b8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16 (CALayer.mm:2524)
    24  QuartzCore                      0x27314580 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 368 (CAContextInternal.mm:1627)
    25  QuartzCore                      0x27314232 CA::Transaction::commit() + 614 (CATransactionInternal.mm:417)
    26  QuartzCore                      0x27341eaa CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 310 (CATransactionInternal.mm:545)
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3e54c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 508 (pthread_tsd.c:217)
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3e14e _pthread_exit + 86 (pthread.c:1308)
    29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3db3c _pthread_wqthread + 1044 (pthread.c:1930)
    30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x24a3d718 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:147)

    Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000001
        r4: 0x40214ba8    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x3aff1304      r7: 0x40214bb8
        r8: 0x0e4704a0    r9: 0x24a3a04d     r10: 0x24f44386     r11: 0x0e4704c4
        ip: 0x00000030    sp: 0x40214ba0      lr: 0x2492b13f      pc: 0x2492b13e
      cpsr: 0x40000030

    Binary Images:
    0x4000 - 0x1a7fff MyApp armv7  <f8372463953c3bac8dfb8498ba403195> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/MyApp
    0x2e4000 - 0x51bfff libswiftCore.dylib armv7  <f3cb04882ec13a0f966883fc2b3a8385> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
    0x6e0000 - 0x6ebfff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib armv7  <81b2b7263e123c5ab7aae384a00fe359> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
    0x700000 - 0x707fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib armv7  <aa8c40985a6730379f6f70de020ab739> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
    0x710000 - 0x717fff libswiftDarwin.dylib armv7  <ea52b77fb1b83b06aad15be523d65fc6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
    0x728000 - 0x72ffff libswiftDispatch.dylib armv7  <f1d9f029029635e79379a020c948d6fb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
    0x738000 - 0x777fff libswiftFoundation.dylib armv7  <cfeba94d47e33e279dee22d48c957dc2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
    0x7a8000 - 0x7affff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib armv7  <620876fa5638364d89e58d271efcec3a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
    0x7bc000 - 0x7c3fff libswiftUIKit.dylib armv7  <594d8e0474bf37b9befe760848a4ad15> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
    0x7d0000 - 0x7d7fff libswiftContacts.dylib armv7  <62422591043e3db0a0ef4528a37e71d7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A65ED66E-398B-4436-8272-A2562A963537/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib
    0x1febe000 - 0x1fee5fff dyld armv7  <623928dbdaf93c6bb910215186f4815f> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x24434000 - 0x24435fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <3dfad2c347673acc91c17bcf3252c0df> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x24436000 - 0x24481fff libc++.1.dylib armv7  <017dba6c16b63f9ebecb9ddd0d0a4520> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x24482000 - 0x2449cfff libc++abi.dylib armv7  <d32373f6c2153a509f6603750d213ffb> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x244a0000 - 0x2480afff libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <94f6d325c1843f45b3a439b86fc9de15> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x2480b000 - 0x2480ffff libcache.dylib armv7  <77c04b32e9b63d5295cc8a721c252137> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x24810000 - 0x24819fff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <1247a256d5003bb58d4000e80cd0db55> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x2481a000 - 0x2481ffff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <f9f0ad8d115c391ca328a2eb9d91a683> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x24820000 - 0x24826fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <d9b8da1ff5283168a21f54b74e5c6cab> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x24827000 - 0x24876fff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <29c4bc7ca4d433828f19c06a5cf3ca32> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x24877000 - 0x248c0fff libdispatch.dylib armv7  <29953b5a3c7c3b0da436b37bec3394f3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x248c1000 - 0x248c3fff libdyld.dylib armv7  <364eae8157b63a128829f2b9dab75538> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x248c4000 - 0x248c4fff libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <d50db9c55305337cac7c5902e9e11ede> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x248c5000 - 0x248c5fff liblaunch.dylib armv7  <d52cdc152878328c903c22e451ad2731> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x248c6000 - 0x248c9fff libmacho.dylib armv7  <f6327d5ee4cc3a14b0c690b0bbb5d495> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x248ca000 - 0x248cbfff libremovefile.dylib armv7  <2d1fd6c142f73c8698e0514b2103df5c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x248cc000 - 0x248defff libsystem_asl.dylib armv7  <9ec60f2ee90130f2b548dbbeec628e5c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x248df000 - 0x248dffff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <b4b8d5044367323a9b129f3a7d81b4e9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x248e0000 - 0x24944fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <88b8e2fdaa173ce2bcbecfafdafca49d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x24945000 - 0x24947fff libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7  <72e4dcd20a443c0eb918ed2a243b309d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x24948000 - 0x2494bfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib armv7  <1cff68c5ac573cca935a8c92c51e8e24> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
    0x2494c000 - 0x2494dfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib armv7  <128b3c55be3d3ec3b86785ca435a9e43> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x2494e000 - 0x2495ffff libsystem_coretls.dylib armv7  <1596440503463c6492f00910534cfeb8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x24960000 - 0x24966fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <78016baa00c4388597f514c308f4aae0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x24967000 - 0x24981fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <c7b2843e7b603832a0430974e4ef035b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x24982000 - 0x2499cfff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7828b66e1d81352fb0c90543407a1355> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x2499d000 - 0x249bdfff libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <4de82221ee263865aaabfbe80c55afc9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x249be000 - 0x249d0fff libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7  <1b1e0207a752307fa30be17aeeaa0606> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x249d1000 - 0x24a24fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <0a3d9d44338136b0b0f9bd3914e7db0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x24a25000 - 0x24a2cfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib armv7  <d766f66f8d1f3d2fa5540d5c20fa63c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x24a2d000 - 0x24a34fff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <949bb4c30f2139db895c612f230f1f1d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x24a35000 - 0x24a3bfff libsystem_platform.dylib armv7  <7a892bf09afb39f28f596dcfb829612e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x24a3c000 - 0x24a43fff libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7  <df1dcaad51bd390cbec131a89706b5be> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x24a44000 - 0x24a46fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <4c67063d8a393d548ff45f595e22ac86> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x24a47000 - 0x24a55fff libsystem_trace.dylib armv7  <2171e90d32aa3f609692c2f8e0d4b1a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x24a56000 - 0x24a56fff libunwind.dylib armv7  <a394593b9bbe3106873aceb3682cd4bd> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x24a57000 - 0x24a57fff libvminterpose.dylib armv7  <6301915f74e33954abe0fa0c1dda0ac2> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
    0x24a58000 - 0x24a76fff libxpc.dylib armv7  <3aae9a195452356fbace176a3dc38e7b> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x24a77000 - 0x24c04fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <4afae3bcf8b73f71bd2917b34cd0a1ff> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x24c05000 - 0x24c11fff libz.1.dylib armv7  <f45b8e232d25324db59b2de0c905946a> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x24c12000 - 0x24f49fff CoreFoundation armv7  <60e1d0255e103eac9a6aeacad668cd6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x24f4a000 - 0x24f56fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <524609a8ee323a04a0fb962be8d816dd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x24f57000 - 0x24f57fff libenergytrace.dylib armv7  <3f0673f65ab53eb3b4501a16140d0384> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
    0x24f58000 - 0x24fb3fff IOKit armv7  <73f25f93c04433a6a1939fa471b09fed> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x24fb4000 - 0x24fd0fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <69a88b36f89e389896bc10b98a8d7dd4> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x24fd1000 - 0x25087fff libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5e5e10a4d19e398d97855e5515691090> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x25088000 - 0x250e3fff Security armv7  <0d5edc7ce0b6392990212b99f013c7c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
    0x250e4000 - 0x2512cfff SystemConfiguration armv7  <16c32558423f3bf58c6b867a4f6ffae3> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x2512d000 - 0x251e4fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <191466f10f943213acae502ee3d48382> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x251e5000 - 0x253ddfff CFNetwork armv7  <7f5e9cd3faec3f6abe1a2e383e0346cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x253de000 - 0x253e8fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <7439fad6b6a836429fa11d711213728b> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x253e9000 - 0x253fefff liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <8ee3facc25bd3957b49ff0b4d657e0ef> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x253ff000 - 0x25414fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <2ca4911a330736688ebd585895af032a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x25415000 - 0x25437fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <e90ef3b8b0b5302b9cbed3d0840a9e0b> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x25438000 - 0x25453fff libextension.dylib armv7  <f3466097cca237faba733b484c0eb6b0> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x25454000 - 0x25458fff liblangid.dylib armv7  <8072b6f6bab438de87ec0e930704c5dc> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x25459000 - 0x25690fff Foundation armv7  <dec9cedc6afc34b98a290f85cf652f71> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x25691000 - 0x2576ffff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b647903060439dd81b6d852b828c808> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x25770000 - 0x25a39fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <76d8234bfe563de18b6a3f8c9727ef6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x25a3a000 - 0x25c92fff vImage armv7  <b0481939c3043e19b603874339d52b73> /System/Library/Frameworks
```

....
....

Comment: The exception is thrown on Thread 7, NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector might give you clue, thrown by NSStringDrawingTextStorageSettings threadSpecificStringDrawingTextStorageSettings:] + 62 (NSStringDrawingTextStorage.m:357)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the cause of the crash but the first thing I'd fix is to make sure anything that touches the UI is happening on the main thread.  In your case, you have layers, views, and buttons referenced off on thread 7.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend you this great Ray's article Demystifying iOS Application Crash Logs: https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: Thanks a lot for all suggestions. @Alex : Thanks a lot for that good link.

Comment: @mcflysoft hope it will help, man :)

Comment: You can also use crash reporting tools, which support symbolification. https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-objc

Comment: @mcflysoft did you found your issue? I am having the same crash but it is very randomly on my case and I can not find the issue.